# jQuery ScrollTop add to this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

a couple of people kindly helped me yesterday with a jQuery issue on a scrollTop function but I now have another small issue.  Below is the fiddle for the js.  I need to get the js to bounce the content back to the top instead of scrolling back up to the top.

Here is the JS, fiddle below it.

```
function scroll(speed) {
    $('.shooter-scroller').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.shooter-scroller').prop('scrollHeight'),
        easing: 'linear'
    }, {
        duration: speed,
        easing: 'linear', // <--- here
        complete: function () {
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, {
                duration: speed,
                easing: 'linear', // <--- here
                complete: speed
            });
        }
    });
}

speed = 8000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function () {
    scroll(speed)
}, speed * 2);
```

});

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andysimps1985/tsb5pj49/)

I need the speed to remain as linear but the scroll to reset to the top once it gets to the bottom.  Any help would be amazing!  Thanks in advance people :)

Comment: What do you mean "the scroll to reset to the top"? Because, for me, the window is gradually scrolled to the bottom, then gradually scrolls to the top again. What browser are you using?

Comment: It needs to automatically bounce to the top of the list once its reached the bottom instead of gradually going back to the top.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You are looking to set it back to the top without animating?

Comment: @grammar thats correct :) once it reaches the bottom of the list, it then to set back to the top with no animation.  Unfortunately I am not amazing with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsb5pj49/4/

Instead of animating it back to the top, you can just set the `scrollTop` to 0 using the same function. Additionally, if you store the `setInterval` in a variable then you can clear it and start it again when the animation completes and the `scrollTop` is reset. Like so:

```
// When DOM is fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var speed = 8000,
        scrollInterval;


    function scroll(speed) {

        $('.shooter-scroller').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.shooter-scroller').prop('scrollHeight'),
            easing: 'linear'
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            easing: 'linear', // <--- here
            complete: onScrollingComplete
        });

    }

    function startScrolling() {
        scroll( speed );
        scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
            scroll(speed)
        }, speed * 2);
    }

    function onScrollingComplete() {
        $( this ).scrollTop( 0 );
        clearInterval( scrollInterval );
        startScrolling();
    }

    startScrolling();

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Grammar, i'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough, once its reset back to the top it needs to scroll to the bottom again, so its one continuous loop, thank you for the quick reply and help though.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for your help!  Yet again stackoverflow comes up trumps with its contributors!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be able to help you out. I have updated the answer to include restarting the animation. Cheers!